# Managing multiple copies of same project as different project under subversion in best way?

Tags: svn, version-control

We have one project built upon asp.net framework 2.0. It is completely tested and working really well. Its an old project and I have requirement to implement same for 3 new sites with just changing a theme. Not a single line of code needs to be changed. All the changes we're anticipating are only in few View files and CSS/images.

How should I manage this?

Should I copy the code and implement it as a different project in subversion and then implement changes for theme? The problem is, if I encounter a bug, I need to fix it separately in all project. Or if there is some new requirement, I need to update in all project.

Or

Is there any other better way to manage this using subversion, so that the bug I fix in one branch can be updated to other project as well.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) instead of copying everything to your new projects.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion might be the wrong tool for this. Use a build system like Ant or Maven (there should be something similar for .NET) which creates a "binary" from your original project to which you can add a dependency from the new projects.

The build system will then make the necessary copies for you, keeping everything in sync.